# KQL query matching values and count

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i am totally new to Kusto and would like somebody advice and help.

I have a file with a lot of data in it. this is a very short sample:

[image: sample data]

what I would like to do, is to compare the `name`,`userID` and count how many times those 2 column repeat themselves in a timespan of minutes (based on the timestamp) or days (just to make it easy I can convert the days in minutes).

The bit of code that I used so far it seems to consider only one of the columns and count, it doesn't check if they appeared before.

this is what I was using:

```
"| summarize count() by bin(_timestamp, 4320m), name, userID"
```

with the correct query, what I am expecting to receive back (assuming that the timestamp is 13:38:01) for all the column, is to have a extra column named `count` and value of `2` for `value 1` and `value 2`

I hope I made my question clear enough, and please if you need more informations, just ask.

Thank you so so much guys

Comment: can you please provide a sample input, and the output you expect for that input?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely following your intention. The below example returns the count per each combination of name, userID, and 3d period, as per your sample data. If this is not the expected output, can you please share the expected input and output in form of a datatable, as below?

```
let T = datatable(_timestamp:datetime, name:string, message:string, userID:string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-26 13:41:16), "value1", "message1", "number1",
    datetime(2021-05-26 13:38:01), "value2", "message2", "number2",
    datetime(2021-05-26 13:41:16), "value1", "message1", "number1",
    datetime(2021-05-26 13:34:05), "value2", "message2", "number2"
];
T
| summarize count() by bin(_timestamp, 3d), name, userID
```

[image]

Comment: you my friend are a hero. That exactly what I was expecting. Just a concern I have. when I run that code, the message column disappears how can I keep all my column and just add the `count_`

Comment: if you don't mind which message is chosen for each combination of user & name, you can use the `any()` aggregation - `T | summarize count(), any(message) by bin(timestamp, 3d), name, userID`. This will choose an arbitrary message per combination. If you need the last/first, you can look into `arg_max()`/`arg_min()`